# CloudWatch Events trigger on shutdown of EC2 instance only if it has a certain tag

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am attempting to trigger a Lambda function when a CloudWatch event detects an EC2 Server that has shutdown. I need this function only to trigger when the EC2 instance contains a certain tag doing this via CloudWatch Events Rules.  In this case, the tag I am using is called nameOfTheTag.

The below JSON is valid for CloudWatch but is not triggering for some reason

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "state": [
      "stopped"
    ],
    "tags:nameOfTheTag": [
      "example"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the lambda trigger from the console or cli? 

One potential thing to check would be the lambda policy if it allows invoke:lambda permission to cloudwatch. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html#intro-permission-model-access-policy

Comment: It does manage to trigger the Lambda if I set the policy to to trigger on any EC2 instance shutdown.

Comment: I am attempting to do the same. But it appears the EC2 Instance State-change Notification itself does NOT send the tags. If you simulate and test by hand-crafting the events with tags, it will trigger the lambda. I am looking for ways to add the tags to the Notification.

Comment: Just came across this question which is almost 3 years old and there's still no option for this in AWS =(

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so this would work as you can't get EC2 with specific tags you only get EC2 Ids